# Cannot resolve symbol 'androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout'

Tags: android

[Cannot resolve symbol 'androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vF1Gu.png)

I made an empty activity in Android Studio, ahead of nothing added, in activity_main.xml, there were so many red lines,and the prompt was: Cannot resolve symbol'

while, these code was generated by Android Studio, I tried file->invalidate cashes/restart... and installed all the SDK tools but Google series. The error was still there.

Gradle was successful, and JDK was installed.

Has anyone a solution ?

Comment: Check your app level gradle dependencies  implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3' this need to be added

Answer (score 0):

Make sure constraint layout is updated to latest version:

```
  implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha3'
```

Comment: dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}

Comment: the gradle dependencies has it.

Comment: I found in Tools->Jshell console:JDK version is 8. JDK 9 or higher is needed to run JShell. Should I update JDK ? I have installed JDK13, while this notification was still there,how can I update it in Android Studio ?

Answer (score 0):

This is because your project support android legacy version, check this out in `build.gradle`, search for this key:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
```

If confirmed, you should use the compatible version instead of the `androidx` version.

That is `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout`.

BTW, are you trying to follow the https://developer.android.com/guide demo? This tutorial sucks.